# How to store data in one to many relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, one-to-many

I want to enter some data from another table and save it in a table. I try to use relationship one to many, but I'm confused to save data

This is my database

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jenis_analisas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('jenis_analisa', 100);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('kategori_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('harga');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('kategori_id')->references('id')->on('kategoris');
        });
    }
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permintaan_analisas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('pelanggan_id');
            $table->string('judul_penelitian', 100);
            $table->string('jenis_contoh', 50);
            $table->string('jumlah_contoh');
            $table->string('asal_contoh', 200);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('jenisanalisa_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('pelanggan_id')->references('id')->on('pelanggans');
            $table->foreign('jenisanalisa_id')->references('id')->on('jenis_analisas');
        });
    }
```

This is my model

```
class JenisAnalisa extends Model
{


    public function kategori()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kategori');
    }

    public function permintaananalisa()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PermintaanAnalisa');
    }
}

class PermintaanAnalisa extends Model
{


    public function jenisanalisa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\JenisAnalisa');
    }
}
```

I want to insert multiple data from jenis_analisas table into permintaan_analisas table.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried entering data using multiple select2, but I get an error array to string conversion

Comment: where is your code to enter data into table?